# extracting time series data where measurements are lowest

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame with a time series measurement. One column is the time and the other is the measurement. When you plot the time series it looks like this:

[image]

By eye the first thing you notice is the short segment where the measurements bottom out for a short period of time. The amount of time this occurs varies. I am trying to figure out a way to pull out the start and end time of that region automatically for 1000's of these kinds of data frames.

The values in that region aren't necessarily the minimum measurements (so I can't set a threshold value for filtering), but they are the longest stretch of lower values.

Comment: You can use something like `rle(mtcars$mpg < 20)`, but you'll need to edit with a sufficient amount of data to reproduce it to get a concrete answer.

Comment: Thank you, the rle command could be very useful. I'm not sure how to use this to get back to the associated time data, however.

Comment: Maybe more robust to find "runs" of  `diff` less than a threshold rather than thresholding the series itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `mtcars` as an example (not ideal, as it's not a time series, but assume it is and it's ordered by time; make your data so, as well):

```
df <- mtcars                    # get sample data
r <- rle(mtcars$mpg < 20)       # save run-length encoding
```

so `r` looks like

```
> r
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:9] 4 3 2 8 4 4 3 3 1
  values : logi [1:9] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

Now rearrange it into a `data.frame`, adding an `index` column for a row number:

```
r <- with(r, data.frame(lengths, values, index = seq_along(r$lengths)))
```

so

```
> head(r)
  lengths values index
1       4  FALSE     1
2       3   TRUE     2
3       2  FALSE     3
4       8   TRUE     4
5       4  FALSE     5
6       4   TRUE     6
```

Add a `run` index and `value` to `df`, using `rep` to repeat each the correct number of times:

```
df$run <- rep(1:nrow(r), times = r$lengths)
df$values <- rep(r$values, times = r$lengths)
```

Chop `r` down to just the rows where `values` are `TRUE`, i.e. where `mpg < 20`:

```
r2 <- r[r$values == TRUE,]
```

Now find the `index` where `r2`'s `lengths` is greatest, i.e. index of the longest run. Use that value to chop `df` down to only those rows, i.e. the rows of the run.

```
df2 <- df[df$run == r2[r2$lengths == max(r2$lengths),'index'],]
```

If you want just the first and last of those rows,

```
> rbind(df2[1,], df2[nrow(df2),])
                   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb run values
Merc 280          19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   4   TRUE
Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4   4   TRUE
```

---

**Note:** `dplyr` could make the syntax here a little more direct, but the steps are pretty much the same.

Comment: this is great. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it's useful! If it answers your question, please consider accepting or upvoting.